# Two transition functions def of NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I've seen a definition of NP alluded to in different texts where at each step an NDTM makes a nondeterministic choice between two transition functions and behaves accordingly. It seems like even in a binary alphabet the machine has more than two possible behaviors.

Can anyone formalize this and help me understand why this is equivalent to more common definitions? Or if anyone had a reference maybe. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose from among four options by first making one binary choice, then making a second binary choice; there are $2\times 2=4$ total possible outcomes, each of which can be mapped to one of those four options.  Similarly, you can choose among any finite set using only binary choices.  That's why the two are equivalent.